# Does Enhance Ability apply to attack based on that ability score?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Is a melee attack a Strength **ability check**, or a missile attack a Dexterity one?

Say a cleric *enhances* the Fighter's Strength — the spell effect says the Fighter now gets advantage on Strength checks. Does that apply to attacks, as they are a form of Strength check?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No.

There are 3 basic d20 roll types in 5e:

- Attack Rolls
- Ability Checks
- Saving Throws

None of these are the same and they are always called out when a roll is called for *which* kind of roll is called for.

So no, you don't get the bonus from Enhance Ability to attacks (or saves for that matter).