# Can 'Enhance Ability' grant targets advantage on attack rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack, advantage-and-disadvantage

*Enhance Ability* (*PHB* 237) is a 2<sup>nd</sup> level spell granting either temporary hitpoints or advantage on any one of the 5 core skills (Str,Dex,Int,Wis,Cha).

It has already been answered several times that [Initiative is a Dexterity check and as such benefits from advantage on such checks](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/98123/can-you-have-advantage-disadvantage-on-your-initiative-check), like ***Cat's Grace*** would bestow from *Enhance Ability*.

I am wondering now about other types of d20 rolls: namely, can a Wizard gain advantage on spell attacks with ***Fox's Cunning***? A rogue or fighter on their weapon attacks with ***Bull's Strength*** and ***Cat's Grace***? A cleric or sorcerer on spells with ***Eagle's Splendor*** or ***Owl's Wisdom***?

*N.B.* I am not concerned about the balance of this, only whether it is permissible based on the rules.

Comment: [Possible duplicate...](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53484/does-enhance-ability-apply-to-attack-based-on-that-ability-score)

Comment: That's indeed a duplicate. That's okay though — duplicates make it easier to find the original, since they serve as pointers from other phrasings that people might search for. Thanks!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Np. I found it by trying to ask the question, as google was giving me a hard time and I was sure it had been asked before. Figured this might help.

Comment: In case it gets modified for a re-open, the editor should modify to indicate that it enhances one of the "6" core "abilities", not "5 core skills". Constitution is overlooked.

Comment: @keithcurtis Constitution is enhanced, but does not get advantage. If you have a better wording, feel free to propose it

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble "Bear’s Endurance. The target has advantage on Constitution checks. It also gains 2d6 temporary hit points, which are lost when the spell ends." Same wording as the others regarding advantage. And it's not worth editing unless the question needs to be re-opened. My comment was a note toward that end.

Comment: @keithcurtis Somehow I missed that in the spell's description... thanks.